# how to render array of only urls in react js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am making a web app which is getting data in the form of http url which are of images eg:

```
let array = ["https://zjcdn.mangafox.me/store/manga/31721/142.0/compressed/m000.jpgtoken=e7bf6b3b8fa25c218502b913a9c722ec374229d6&ttl=1633968000","https://zjcdn.mangafox.me/store/manga/31721/142.0/compressed/m001.jpg?token=3cd1bb77873151a1311e0f87d3cdd68100045326&ttl=1633968000",     "https://zjcdn.mangafox.me/store/manga/31721/142.0/compressed/m002.jpg?token=74b31d27c19d32b1abb3db47eeb97a5cb4f381c7&ttl=1633968000","https://zjcdn.mangafox.me/store/manga/31721/142.0/compressed/m003.jpg?token=ff06277b89a5764deccae021411342de9947f130&ttl=1633968000","https://zjcdn.mangafox.me/store/manga/31721/142.0/compressed/m004.jpg?token=a5641dc8ed4d61de17793f94a45e69ab38f5fce3&ttl=1633968000","https://zjcdn.mangafox.me/store/manga/31721/142.0/compressed/m005.jpg?token=659f9f64adad8356006bc939365b492004bedc12&ttl=1633968000","https://zjcdn.mangafox.me/store/manga/31721/142.0/compressed/m006.jpg?token=46641b886d2eef796860c5d29e2959e4cb621945&ttl=1633968000","https://zjcdn.mangafox.me/store/manga/31721/142.0/compressed/m007.jpg?token=6c8ff51fd06f5a0171bde3e3bee2c68606985918&ttl=1633968000"]
```

and I want to render them on page I have used following code:

```
`{ 
       arr.map(e=>{
           return <img src={`${e}`} alt="" />  
       })
         
       } `
```

and this:

`arr.map(e=> (<img src={e} alt="" />))`

but the problem is it is only rendering one image instead of rendering all images.

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:react-router] and [tag:hooks] when that's not mentioned in your question? Should also [edit] and post the entire component.

Comment: arr is formed by pushing data from the useState hook for convenience of reader i didn't type it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have got some issues with your array as it would appear is has some format problems. Here is the [fix](https://jsfiddle.net/hypothesis/eLyk26x5/7/)

```
{
array.map((el,i )=> <img key={i} src={el} /> )
}
```

Comment: no dude it is still returning 1 image i i have tried many things

Comment: Yes dude. If you look at the link you can see it is rendering all the pictures.

Comment: thanks problem is solved ......... dude